# How can I escape a comma when creating a CSV file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, csv

I'm writing to a CSV file in Node.js and I'd like to add a hyperlink to some of the fields, as the `=HYPERLINK` function can be recognized by excel and some other spreadsheet apps.

So for example, I have this function

```
const addHyperlink = (url, str) => `=HYPERLINK("${url}", "${str}")`;
```

And the function is used as follows:

```
const processToCSVFormat = () => {
  ...
  return `${author}, ${date}, ${addHyperlink(purchaseURL, title)}, ...`
}
```

The issue is of course that when the CSV is parsed in Excel, it picks up the comma and separates the function into the next column, like

```
Column 1 | =HYPERLINK("https://google.com" | "Google") | Column 4 | Column 5 | ...
```

I know that the comma needs to be escaped, but I've been unable to get it working looking at past answers - I may be doing it incorrectly though. I tried:

```
return `${author}, ${date}, "${addHyperlink(purchaseURL, title)}", ...`
```